# App not hideable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I know that it is possible to make a NSWindow unhideable.

But is it also possible, is there a property, to tell the compiler to make the whole app  not hideable ?

Comment: No. Why would you want that?

Comment: @duskwuff, perhaps he wants to make a daemon.... Or a virus

Comment: If you were trying to make a true daemon, it wouldn't be exposed as an application at all. Or, if it were a background application, there's `NSUIElement`.

Comment: It sounds s/he's asking to make the app stay *visible*, not stay hidden.

Comment: You mean to ignore invocations of the Hide command/menu item from the application menu? Or do you mean you want the app to always be in front of all other apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to emulate this behavior, since I don't see a property to do it, is to remove the `Hide` action from the menu bar. Since that controls the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut. But then if you have a dock icon the user could right click it and hide it there. So you could respond to [`NSApplicationDelegate`'s](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/) `applicationWillHide:` and `applicationDidHide:` methods and then show your application again. Although I don't think this sounds like a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

For a single window, you use `-[NSWindow setCanHide:]` to control whether it can become hidden.

If you want to disable hiding entirely, you would probably need to subclass `NSApplication` to override `hide` with an empty implementation. I've never tried this, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work without trouble. Of course you should also remove the "Hide" option from your main menu. (Note that just doing that would not be sufficient, since you would still respond to other applications' sending `hideOtherApplications:`.)